# Discord.py: Message not getting sent to channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a command that has the user place an order for something, and when this order is placed for it to send a message of the order to a specific channel. Now, I have this done in my `main.py` file, but this is in a cog and I'm having some issues. I don't understand what the problem here is.

```
await client.wait_until_ready()
channel = ctx.client.get_channel(851150407849213992)
await channel.send(order) # order is already defined previously
```

Comment: You either have to replace `ctx.client.get_channel` with `self.client.get_channel` or give us more details.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Can you accept my answer so we can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ctx.client.get_channel` with `self.client.get_channel`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a cog, you must include `self`
Here's the code how to fix it

```
await client.wait_until_ready()
channel = self.client.get_channel(851150407849213992)
await channel.send(order) # order is already defined previously
```